# Design With HTML5 and Coding with JAVA (android native codes)

Tags: java, android, xml, html, webview

Frnds I am new to android app development.I got some ideas while studying about webviews in android.

I Want to design android app using html5 css3 and javascript.
And coding functionalities be in java ( Android Native) is it possible?

Help me to get clear idea and pls give some example.

Comment: yes, read the doc : http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: its just told toast function my doubt is ..if i am creating a login and registeration screen using html5 , css3 and validation using javascript and the coding part of native android java code how it gets the textid from the html. I want to get the login username password text and pass them to webservice. Is it possible? and how ?

Comment: @njzk2 is right. As for accessing input fields, you'll have to pass the values from Javascript to the native code, not the other way round.

Comment: pls give me some examples to understand how to pass the values from javascript to native java code(android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to lear Phonegap for html designing also you can do java coding. From this simple program you will get to know .Follow this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-android-hello-world-application-with-phonegap--mobile-2532)